# Why does the nuxt loader come up instead of the response?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, bun

I just make the nuxt 3 app with graphql. Although in development mode everything works fine, in production there is such a problem: instead of response to any request to api (and not only) comes the nuxt loader code. See the screenshots

[In bun run dev, all fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzDPd.png)

[In bun run build and npx serve .output/public (also, if you upload to the server, the result is the same). Nuxt loader instead of response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8v2X.png)

[Nuxt loader instead of hook.js (part 1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jovJa.png)

[Nuxt loader instead of hooks.js (part 2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcY91.png)

My nuxt.config.ts

```
// https://nuxt.com/docs/api/configuration/nuxt-config
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  sourcemap: {
    server: true,
    client: true
  },
  ssr: false,
  nitro: {
    preset: 'service-worker'
  },
  build: {
        transpile: ["primevue"]
    },
  modules: [
    // ...
    '@pinia/nuxt',
    '@nuxtjs/apollo',
    'vue3-carousel-nuxt',
  ],
  devtools: { enabled: true },
  pinia: {
    autoImports: [
      // automatically imports `defineStore`
      'defineStore', // import { defineStore } from 'pinia'
      ['defineStore', 'definePiniaStore'], // import { defineStore as definePiniaStore } from 'pinia'
    ],
  },
  apollo: {
    autoImports: true,
    authType: 'Session',
    authHeader: 'woocommerce-session',
    tokenStorage: 'cookie',
    tokenName: 'woocommerce-session',
    clients: {
      default: {
        httpEndpoint: 'https://ojuvi.by/api/graphql',
      },
    },
  },
  css: ["~/public/css/style.less"],
});
```

I don't understand what's wrong, I've tried googling but I can't find anything like that.